Does the verb "encantar" only take indirect objects? Why does it not take direct objects?
Encantar, like gustar, means to please/be pleasing to. So I would expect the sentence structure to be:
object (thing(s) getting pleased) + conjugation of encantar in accordance with subject + subject (thing(s) doing the pleasing).
But it seems that indirect object pronouns are used instead. For example,
A Peppa y a George les encanta jugar en los charcos de barro
(Peppa and George love to play in the muddy puddles),
where we use "les" even after mentioning the objects (a Peppa y a George) because, as I understand it, you need to use the indirect object pronoun even if you mention the indirect object explicitly.
Is there a reason we use indirect object pronouns (instead of direct object pronouns) with encantar and gustar? I.e, why isn't the sentence:
A Peppa y a George encanta jugar en los charcos de barro,
or, if Peppa and George were already mentioned,
Los encanta jugar en los charcos de barro?

Les encanta jugar en los charcos. Algo [le] encanta a alguien: objeto indirecto. You can try the RAE before posting. Many questions are answered by the dictionary.

OP know that it is an indirect object; they just don't understand why.

Diccionario panhispánica de dudas
encantar

Con el sentido de 'someter a poderes mágicos', es transitivo: «María se acordaba de su voz, […] que todo lo encantaba» (Pombo Metro [Esp. 1990]).

Cuando significa 'gustar mucho', es intransitivo; lo que gusta o agrada funciona como sujeto y el complemento de persona es indirecto: «A Fabio le encanta crear complicaciones» (Shand Delmonte [Arg. 1987]); «A los griegos les encantaba la mitología» (Mundo [Esp.] 30.9.1995).


encantar

Verbs of liking and disliking are among the verbs known as "verbos de afección" (verbs of feeling), mentioned under 35.5l here:
aburrir, agobiar, agradar, alegrar, asombrar, asustar, atraer, cansar, complacer, contentar, desagradar, disgustar, divertir, doler, encantar, entristecer, entusiasmar, escocer, estimular, extrañar, gustar, herir, interesar, irritar, molestar, obsesionar, ofender, pesar, preocupar, sorprender
As specified under 35.5m, these verbs take the indirect object "le/s" to refer to the person experiencing the feeling, while the subject refers to the thing causing it:

A Peppa y a George les encanta jugar en los charcos de barro (Playing in muddy puddles - subject causing the feeling of pleasure - appeals to Peppa and George - object experiencing the pleasure).


Right, my question is why is it that indirect objects are used with encantar instead of direct object?

Actually, "encantar" with a direct object sounds weird. Other verbs like "hechizar" or "embrujar" would be used instead: Sus ojos lo hechizaron / lo embrujaron / (?) lo encantaron.

This a logical explanation (not documented and not backed by Spanish grammar experts), but it has worked very well in my classes.
The meaning of the verb "gustar" is "to give like-feeling" = "dar gusto".
"Gusto" is the Direct Object and it is implicit inside the verb "gustar".
A Peppa y a George les gusta jugar en los charcos de barro.
"jugar en los charcos de barro" is the subject of the sentence, which means that "jugar en los charcos de barro" gives like-feeling. Peppa and George are the people who receive like-feeling, therefore, they are the Indirect Object.
Look at the sentence this way:
Jugar en los charcos de barro les da gusto a Peppa y a George.
The verb "encantar" works in the say way, but it gives "encanto".
